# Spinner is not working properly with BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-design-library, bottom-sheet

I'm facing issue with `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. I have used `Spinner` in `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, for BottomSheet I'm using
`'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'` dependency.
Now problem is with `Spinner`, when I select item from spinner it remains default one on upfront of spinner even `onItemSelected` is not calling.
But when I remove this line `mBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED)` Spinner is working fine but after changing item of spinner `BottomSheet` drags bit down so I have to drag it up again.

I have tried `com.android.support:design:25.2.0` everything is working fine with `25.2.0`, but I want it to work properly with `23` because my whole project is using `23.2.0` only

below is my code for BottomSheetDialogFragment

```
public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style)
{
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
    mBottomSheetView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.abc_layout, null);
    dialog.setContentView(mBottomSheetView);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface)
        {

            BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = (BottomSheetDialog) dialogInterface;
            FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
            mBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(frameLayout);
            mBehavior.setHideable(false);
            mBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }
    });

    mTermAdapter = new TermSpinnerAdapter(getContext(), mTermList);

    mTermSpinner.setAdapter(mTermAdapter);

    mTermSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "onItemSelected: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        {
        }
    });

    mAssessmentSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "onItemSelected: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        {
        }
    });
}
```